# Performance Metrics for TempDB

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, performance, tempdb

I've been tasked with gathering performance metrics on a few database servers that have one TempDB data file.  It seems prevailing wisdom is to have one TempDB data file per core up to a certain point.  Both servers in question have 4 CPUs, so we're going to add three more on each.

My question is which performance metrics should I gather to get a solid depiction of where my servers are at?  I want to gather data pre-change and post-change for comparison.

Comment: For an excellent article about this problem, see http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2011/04/21/analyzing-tempdb-contention-a-month-of-activity-monitoring-part-21-of-30.aspx